# python - Verify if a url is a video raw file link without urllib.request.urlopen

Tags: python, video, urllib

I want to verify if a url is video raw file link or not, for example:

http://hidden_path/video_name.mp4

Below is my current code:

```
def is_video(url):
    r = None
    try:
        r = urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}))
    except:
        return False
    content_type = r.getheader("Content-Type")
    if re.match("video*", content_type):
        return True
    return False
```

This code will have issue if the video url is a big video, and it may cause timeout error on server.

Are there any better approaches?

Comment: Could checking for a HTTP download header work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to check the `Content-Type` of the header you can send a `HEAD` request instead of the `GET`.

Once you have obtained the response from the `HEAD` request you can check for `video` in the `Content-Type` header as above.

Example:

```
>>> req = urllib.request.Request(url, method='HEAD', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
>>> r = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
>>> r.getheader('Content-Type')
'video/mp4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this does it

```
import mimetypes
url = 'http://media.theaterchurch.com/podcast/video/hd/720p/2016/05-08-16-720p.mp4'
print mimetypes.MimeTypes().guess_type(url)[0]
```

outputs this...

```
video/mp4
```