# how to check if user message is a video?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make an event that reacts to a user message in a specific channel when it's a video. I got the channel part out of the way but am stuck on how to check if the message is a video or not. Here is my code so far:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.channel.id == 841096210496094208:
      await message.add_reaction("✅")
      await message.add_reaction("❌")
    else:
      return
```

Comment: What have you attempted to check if it's a video?  Do you want the video to be a link or a file?

Comment: I have no idea what i could possibly use, I tried having it see if the message contains a certain string in the beggining, so something like "www.youtube.com", but i realized that's pretty inefficient since there are other sites that have videos. I want it to react to both links and files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to loop over `Message.attachments`, use the `content_type` attribute to check whether it's a video or an image

```py
async def on_message(message):
    for attch in message.attachments:
         attch_type, attch_format = attch.content_type.split('/') # Attachment.content_type returns a {type}/{file_format} string
         if attch_type == 'video':
            print("Contains video")
```

*PS: This will check only if a message contains a video, not a URL to a video*

#### References:

- [`Message.attachments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.attachments)
- [`Attachment.content_type`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Attachment.content_type)

Comment: Thank you!! Also would I be able to do the same thing to see if it's a link?

Comment: This solution will not work for video URLs, and honestly I don't think there's one straightforward answer to that, video links differ a lot from each other, maybe you can try making an API request to the link(s) in the message and check if it's a video link, maybe this question will also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267871/python-verify-if-a-url-is-a-video-raw-file-link-without-urllib-request-urlopen

Comment: You should also check if the video contains an URL, you can do it with a regex, feel free to research this topic